# I want to fetch user information from index page using fetch

Tags: javascript, html

1. After successful login, you will be directed to /index.
2. Retrieve user information by using fetch with JavaScript within the index page.
3. At this time, it moves to the url used for fetch, not to the index page.
   Why?
   I just want to apply the value of the object response from fetch to index.html.

This is the code in error

```js
//index.html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id='user'></div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>

//index.js
const id = document.getElementById('user');
fetch('/api/user')
.then((res)=>res.json)
.then((data)=>{
 id.innerText = data.userid})
```

[When you access the index page, the corresponding screen appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISEBv.png)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make out what you're asking in the question, but `.then((res)=>res.json)` is incorrect, it should be `.then((res)=>res.json())` (notice the `()` after `res.json`). Also, you should be checking `res.ok` before calling it (I go into details on that [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your redirection/login code, not what you posted here. If you post that, maybe we could help further.

Comment: It moves to the action /login entered in the form, and when login is done using Spring security, it moves to the /index page.  Any problem with this?
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureHandler(customAuthFailureHandler)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")